# How to instantiate a child singleton of an abstract class?

Tags: php, singleton, abstract-class

I have an abstract class and a child that extends the abstract class. The child is supposed to be a sigleton. Here is simplified example of the abstract class:

```
abstract class AbstractClass{
    protected static $instance = NULL;
    abstract protected function meInit();

    private function __construct(){
        $this->meInit();
        $this->init();
    }

    private function __clone(){}

    static function getInstance(){
        if (is_null(self::$instance)){
           self::$instance=new self;
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    function init(){
        'code here;

    }
}
```

Here is simplified child class:

```
class ChildClass_A extends AbstractClass{

    protected function meInit(){
        'some code;
    }
}
```

When I try to get an instance of the child `$child = ChildClass_A::getInstance();` I get this error:

> Fatal error: Cannot instantiate abstract class AbstractClass in
>   C:\wamp\www\Classes\AbstractClass.php on line 7

I suspect the culprit is in `self::$instance=new self;`. How should I redo it to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're almost there; you just can't use `new self()` like this because it's trying to do a `new A()`. Instead, use `get_called_class()` so that a new `B` is created instead.

```
// ONLY SUPPORTS ONE SUBCLASS
// KEEP READING BELOW FOR COMPLETE SOLUTION
abstract class A {

    static protected $instance = null;

    abstract protected function __construct();

    static public function getInstance() {
        if (is_null(self::$instance)) {
            $class = get_called_class();
            self::$instance = new $class();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

}

class B extends A {
    protected function __construct() {
        echo "constructing B\n";
    }
}

var_dump(B::getInstance()); // constructing B, object(B)#1 (0) {}
var_dump(B::getInstance()); // object(B)#1 (0) {}
```

OK, but what happens now when we try to make another subclass?

```
class C extends A {
    protected function __construct() {
        echo "constructing C\n";
    }
}

var_dump(C::getInstance()); // object(B)#1 (0) {}
var_dump(C::getInstance()); // object(B)#1 (0) {}
```

Well that sucks! I wanted a `C` instance, not the `B` one! This is because the abstract class *A* is only saving one instance. We have to make it support one of each subclass.

Well that's easy!

```
// SOLUTION:
// WORKS FOR MULTIPLE SUBCLASSES
abstract class A {

    static protected $instances = array();

    abstract protected function __construct();

    static public function getInstance() {
        $class = get_called_class();
        if (! array_key_exists($class, self::$instances)) {
            self::$instances[$class] = new $class();
        }
        return self::$instances[$class];
    }

}
```

Class `B` and `C` can stay the same ...

```
class B extends A {
    protected function __construct() {
        echo "constructing B\n";
    }
}

class C extends A {
    protected function __construct() {
        echo "constructing C\n";
    }
}
```

Now let's check out how they behave

```
var_dump(B::getInstance()); // constructing B, object(B)#1 (0) {}
var_dump(B::getInstance()); // object(B)#1 (0) {}

var_dump(C::getInstance()); // constructing C, object(C)#2 (0) {}
var_dump(C::getInstance()); // object(C)#2 (0) {}
```

Oh good! Just what we always wanted!

Comment: You're the winner! was going to comment the same thing :D

Comment: yes, I think you're right. However, `static private $instance` needs to be changed to `static protected $instance`, else it doesn't work because the child class doesn't have access to it.

Comment: Also, I just realized, using `static` instead of `self` would work, too.

Comment: Correct the `private` to `protected` and I'll accept your answer

Comment: @user2395238 I also think it would be best to use an `abstract protected __construct` in this case (instead of making up your own `init` methods). See my revised answer.

Comment: Good catch. Your answer is now perfect.